# VS code saying application finished when running flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run my flutter app on vs code it's saying application finished, Exited (Sigterm). It was working just fine last night but I woke up today and I tried to run it and it started doing it.
I am trying to run the app and work on it, not install it to my device, but for some reason vs code keeps installing it.

Comment: Please Post the error output as well to figure out the cause

Comment: That's the thing, there is no error. This is all I'm getting. https://drive.google.com/file/d/14L9_31mnRhbKLIKSiujAWNzlLvuuHNPi/view?usp=sharing

It seems vs code is running the command flutter install instead of flutter run

Comment: Seems to be the issue with the device connectivity, this happens when device gets disconnected while build

Comment: Ohh I see let me try use a new cable

Comment: I tried a different cable and it's still not working, but when I go to the terminal and run flutter run the app runs perfectly

Comment: Please try running the **Dart: Capture Debugging Logs** command and then reproduce the issue. Then click **Cancel** on the logging notification to stop logging and open the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the exact solution but it worked for me, this is what I ended up doing. It seems it was a storage/temporary files issue so I cleared up some storage on my PC then I went to %temp% and deleted everything there and it started working again